# How to disable confirmation for large files

Tags: dired, tramp

When you recursively copy a large remote directory through Tramp, it will ask for confirmation for large files. Because of that, you can't leave the copy in the background, since the confirmation pauses the copy. And the "large file" size is something ridiculous, like 10MB.

How do I disable this? It really slows down the copy process.

Comment: Explain how you're copying. You added tag `dired`, so perhaps you're using that? Please provide a more complete description/recipe for the problem.

Comment: Also please add the *exact* message you get.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled with `large-file-warning-threshold` variable.

Do `C-h v large-file-warning-threshold RET`.

Then hit `customize`.

Then hit `Value Menu`.

Then choose `"Never request confirmation"`.

However, setting it globally affects more than just tramp copy (open large file, for instance). So you may wanna limit its usage with finer control.